# AKKA.NET and DeathWatchNotification

Tags: akka.net

I get the following message when a **ProductActor** tries to Tell a **ValidatorActor** to validate the message. Although I see this message, I get the expected result.

I did not try to send a message from **ProductActor** to itself. Why still I get the following message?

```
[INFO][5/17/2015 8:06:03 AM][Thread 0012][akka://catalogSystem/user/productActor] Message DeathWatchNotification from akka://catalogSystem/user/productActor to akka://catalogSystem/user/productActor was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
```

--UPDATE--

The two actors are given below:

```
public class ProductActor : UntypedActor
{
    protected override void OnReceive(object message)
    {
        if (message is ReportableStatusChanged)
        {
            _reportableState = ((ReportableStatusChanged) message).ReportableState;
        }
        else
        {
            if (message is RetrieveProductState)
            {
                var state = new ProductState()
                {
                    ReportableState = _reportableState
                };

                Sender.Tell(state);
            }
            else
            {
                Context.ActorSelection("akka://ProductSystem/user/ProductActor/validator").Tell(message);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ProductValidatorActor()), "validator");

        base.PreStart();
    }

    private IReportableState _reportableState;
}

public class ProductValidatorActor : UntypedActor
{
    protected override void OnReceive(object message)
    {
        if (message is ChangeReportableStatus)
        {
            Sender.Tell(new ReportableStatusChanged(ReportableStates.ReportableState));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test to check the status:

```
class ChangeReportableStatusTest
{
    public void Do()
    {
        var system = ActorSystem.Create("catalogSystem");

        var ProductActor = system.ActorOf(Props.Create<ProductActor>(), "productActor");
        ProductActor.Tell(new ChangeReportableStatus(true));

        Thread.Sleep(50);

        var state = ProductActor.Ask<ProductState>(new RetrieveProductState());

        Console.WriteLine("Reportable State: " + (state.Result.ReportableState == ReportableStates.ReportableState ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"));

        system.Shutdown();
        system.AwaitTermination();

        Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to terminate.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of both your actors?

Comment: I updated the question with the code. Please note that I have three messages namely (1) ChangeReportableStatus (2) ReportableStatusChanged (3) RetrieveProductState

Answer (score 5):

You're getting a dead letters notification, which means that the message you're trying to send is not deliverable. The actor you're trying to send a message to may be dead, or it may have never existed. In this case, it appears to be the latter.

I noticed that the name of the `ActorSystem` that your `ProductActor` lives within is different in your error message (`catalogSystem`) vs your code (`ProductSystem`).

With your `ActorSelection`, you're sending a message to an actor path in the wrong `ActorSystem`, to an actor path where no actor exists. Hence the DeadLetters notice. Assuming `ProductActor` is created as a top-level actor in the `catalogSystem`, the path you're trying to send to is correct (`/user/ProductActor/validator`), but the actor system name is not (should be `catalogSystem` but here it is `ProductSystem`).

#### How to fix it

So how do you fix it? Two options:

1. Use the correct path in your `ActorSelection` like so: `Context.ActorSelection("akka://catalogSystem/user/ProductActor/validator").Tell(message);`. While this *works*, it's the wrong answer.
2. Since you create the `ProductValidatorActor` as a child of the `ProductActor`, just store the `IActorRef` of the child in the parent, and send messages to it directly. This is the approach I recommend. In this particular case, you don't need an `ActorSelection` at all.

### It works now, but what can we learn here?

There are two lessons to take from this.

#### Lesson 1: don't use an `ActorSelection` when don't need it

Generally, you should be `Tell`ing messages to `IActorRef`s, not to `ActorSelection`s. With an `IActorRef`, you **know** that the actor has existed at some point in time in the past. This is a guarantee of the Akka framework, that all `IActorRef`s have existed at some point, even if the actor is now dead.

With an `ActorSelection`, you have no such guarantee. It's kind of like [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)—you're just firing messages at an address with no idea if anyone is listening.

This brings up the question of "so when should I use an `ActorSelection`?" The guideline I follow is to use an `ActorSelection` when:

1. I need to take advantage of wildcard selection in actor paths for some reason.
2. I need to send an initial message to an actor on a remote actor system, so I don't actually have a handle to it yet (and don't have a guarantee that it ever ex

#### Lesson 2: don't fat finger actor paths in your actor code

If you need to use `ActorSelection`s, put the paths in a shared class and then have all your other actors reference that class. Something like this:

```cs
using Akka.Actor;

namespace ProductActors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static helper class used to define paths to fixed-name actors
    /// (helps eliminate errors when using <see cref="ActorSelection"/>)
    /// </summary>
    public static class ActorPaths
    {
        public static readonly ActorMetaData ProductValidatorActor = new ActorMetaData("validator", "akka://ProductActors/user/validator");
        public static readonly ActorMetaData ProductCoordinatorActor = new ActorMetaData("coordinator", "akka://ProductActors/user/commander/coordinator");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Meta-data class
    /// </summary>
    public class ActorMetaData
    {
        public ActorMetaData(string name, string path)
        {
            Name = name;
            Path = path;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public string Path { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

... which can then be referenced like so:

```cs
Context.ActorSelection(ActorPaths.ProductValidatorActor.Path).Tell(message);
```

Comment: I corrected the original post with the actor system being used which is 'catalogSystem' (not 'productSystem').

Comment: Yes, but in your `ProductActor` you are still sending your message to `ProductSystem` : `Context.ActorSelection("akka://ProductSystem/user/ProductActor/validator").Tell(message);`

Comment: @wonderfulworld that's exactly the problem. With your `ActorSelection`, you're sending a message to a validator address in a different ActorSystem, to an actor which doesn't actually exist. Hence the DeadLetters notice. You're sending to an actor path where no actor exists. On that note, since you're creating the `ProductValidatorActor` as a child of the `ProductActor`, why would you use an `ActorSelection` at all? Just store the `IActorRef` and send messages to that.

Comment: I tested with both the ActorSelection as well as the instance of the child actor. I see the problem in both the situations. In both cases, I see that the validator.OnReceive is accessed, so the validator is existing in the same actor system. I get the expected result also. You have already noticed that I see the message when System.Shutdown is run. Please refer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/cykkvflcagY for an issue already with AKKA.

Comment: There is a reason why I used the ActorSelection and not the child actor. I'm progressing to a point where I have a few validators (product category). These validators should not be the child of a product actor. There can be thousands of product actors. These products may belong to five categories. So there may be only five validators. These validators are worker actors that don't have any states. I'm still a beginner at AKKA, but just sharing my ideas. Please share whether that design make sense.

Comment: @wonderfulworld sure, you can do that. You have many options. You could easily find pass in the `IActorRef` dependencies or look them up via the shared static class in a strategy pattern-esque way. Really up to you.

Comment: I changed the ActorSelection to IActorRef. The problem still exists. I will probably open a bug.

Comment: @wonderfulworld suggest you go ask for help in the [Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/akkadotnet/akka.net) first.